# Evaluating complicated mathematical exprerssion in Java given as String

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [using eval in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605032/using-eval-in-java)
>   [Is there a java equivalent of the python eval function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7143343/102937)

How can I evaluate complicated mathematical expressions (with trigonometric functions) in Java, given as a String such as the following (say given angles are in degrees):

```
3 + 8 - ( 8 + sin(30) + 5 - 3 * 2 + (8 - 5 * 6) ) * cosec(45)
```

Please suggest any production quality third party libraries if available, or suggest suitable algorithm / data structure if I have to do the boilerplate coding myself.

Comment: JEP: http://www.singularsys.com/jep/ (There should be an older free version available somewhere too, but the licence is cheap enough if it's an important feature.)

Comment: @Robert Harvey The threads mentioned as duplicates are not dealing trigonometric functions.

Comment: For that, you are going to need an industrial-strength library, like the one @millimoose suggests.

Comment: @Robert Harvey Well, then why did you close my thread? It is unique thread and there are things to discuss! (and there are people to answer)

Comment: This isn't a discussion forum, or a substitute for Google.  Do some of your own research, and come back here if you get stuck.

Comment: @Robert Harvey You closed my thread as duplicate, after finding not duplicate, you are saying something else!!

Comment: I can change the close reason, if you like.  But nobody here is going to hand you a complete solution.  The linked posts provide a good starting point if you decide to code a solution yourself.

Comment: @Robert Harvey Thank you for accepting the reason you closed my thread is wrong. (and please mention the correct reason)

Comment: @DUKE The answers on the duplicates a) point to third-party libraries as well (http://stackoverflow.com/a/2605050/41655), and b) the ones that suggest an embedded scripting language are also a valid approach even if you need more than standard arithmetic (Rhino will have access to `Math.sin`, and you can declare new toplevel functions in the JS engine if you want to avoid having to write that prefix.) This is enough to justify "duplicate" as a close reason, insofar as you haven't really investigated at whether the duplicates satisfy your requirements.

Comment: @DUKE, see: https://gist.github.com/4446583

Comment: @Bart Kiers **THANKS VERY MUCH!**. This is exactly what I have been looking for. **Thanks again!**